# Unable to upgrade to selenium 4.1.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: selenium

I'm unable to upgrade selenium to version 4.1.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

```
root@server:~# pip3 install selenium --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from selenium)
```

Checking the version:

```
root@server:~# python3 -c "import selenium; print(selenium.__version__)"
3.141.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to its [documentation](https://%20https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) Selenium 4 requires python3.7. So in your case, you need to install python3.7 and then install selenium 4 in that environment.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!